# creates variables in loop or fromArray

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

So i have a little problem that i cant figure out and not sure how to do it 
so i have a loop that creates form boxes and im gonna send all of them to a excel file(but thats later) 
now i just want to create all variables in the loop

here is the loop with 1 textbox just to show

```
<?php

$i=1;
while ($i<=31){
?>

<input type = "text" name="day" />
<br />

<?php
$i=$i+1;
 }

?>
```

so now how do i create a unique name for each box? or whats the best way to do it i read that array, fromarray is good at it if so im not good with arrays so how do i do it?

Comment: `name="day<?php echo $i; ?>"` or `name="day[]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input name like `day[]`

```
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<=31){
    ?>
    <input type = "text" value="day<?php echo $i; ?>" name="day[]" />
    <br />
    <?php
    $i++;
 }
?>
```

When you process form value with GET/POST like bellow (My example with POST) :

```
<?php
$days = $_POST['day'];
foreach($days as $day) {
     echo $day;
}
?>
```

Or Like this :

```
<input list="day" name="day" class="listbox">
<datalist id="day">
    <?php
    $i=1;
    while ($i<=31){
        ?>
        <option value="day<?php echo $i; ?>">Day <?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php
        $i++;
     }
    ?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Ok so i guess thats Array right? or will they get like day1,day2,day3 etc?

Comment: Yes, now `day` input field is array. I have updated my answer. Follow that

Comment: when i tested this i get value="day<?php echo $i; ?>"  in every box like [day1][day2] etc when i removed  value="day<?php echo $i; ?>" i dident how do i change so i dont get the name of everybox i just want them blank like this [      ]

Comment: can you share your full html form with me?

Comment: oh damn was wrong code still i got new link https://jsfiddle.net/crz4d6yt/ php doesent work tho but you can see the code

Comment: nvm im just dumb value="day<?php echo $i; ?>" is just to show the variable right ? all i need to make this work is name="day[]"?

Comment: try this : `<input list="day" name="day" class="listbox">
<datalist id="day">
 <?php
 $i=1;
 while ($i<=31){
  ?>
  <option value="day<?php echo $i; ?>">Day <?php echo $i; ?></option>
  <?php
  $i++;
  }
 ?>
</datalist>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
<?php

    $i=1;
    while ($i<=31){

      echo  '<input type = "text" name="day' . $i .'" /><br />';
      $i=$i+1;
    }

?>
```

Comment: oh that simple so this will give me day1, day2,day3 etc?

Comment: yes  .. . if you need somthings else .. please explain your need

Answer (score 0):

this is a good place to use a for loop instead of the while loop:

```
<?php
  for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
?>
  <input type = "text" name="day-<?= $i ?>" />
  <br />
<?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: yeah, here's the output:

Comment: <input type = "text" name="day-1" />
    <br />

    <input type = "text" name="day-2" />
    <br />...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$i=1;
while ($i<=31){
   echo '<input type = "text" name="Random' . $i . '" /><br />';
   $i++;
}
?>
```

And btw. you can do operations on variables much easier like this [Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php/)